# AngularJS and rails cors headers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cors

Im trying to build an angular spa but have trouble with cors. My api runs on rails.

GET requests works without problem but POST, PUT, DELETE does not work. The message is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3001/api/resources. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In rails I have a before_filter with this code:

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' 
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*' 
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
```

And in routes:

```
match '/*path' => 'sessions#home', :via => :options
```

In angular config I set this:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Any ideas on this? Im on mac, localhost btw

EDIT

This message is shown in headers in chromes network tab:

```
CAUTION: provisional headers are shown
```

Comment: have you tried in more than one browser?  I have had that problem in chrome believe it or not but it worked fine in Firefox.

Comment: Can you post the request / response details ?

Comment: Added the only thing I could think would be important. See post

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with the rails configuration.

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) it is stated:

> ...We may want to disable CSRF protection for APIs since they are typically designed to be state-less. That is, the request API client will handle the session for you instead of Rails....

Though not with Angular (which I think the problem is irrelevant), [this repo](https://github.com/MehmetKaplan/SPACORSRAILSSample) (that I recently prepared) may help for anyone that runs to this issue. It has a step by step guide to prepare a skeleton for a Rails SPA that uses CORS.

Answer (score -2):

There are options to disable web security in Chrome to allow cross domain requests, but that is never the best way to go about it.

On a mac:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

Or try with `dataType: 'JSONP'` in your ajax call.